# Probabilities...

Tags: probability

I'd like to reproduce what [this site](https://www.bustabit.com/play) does but I have no idea how to do so.

It basically starts from 1.0x then depending on some luck, it will go up and crash/bust at a certain number, which is random.

The highest the crash happens at, the lower chance it had to happen.
The probability it crashes @ 2x or higher is of 49.5%

Here are some more

```
Probability of >= 1: 99%
Probability of >= 2: 49.5%
Probability of >= 3: 33%
Probability of >= 4: 24.75%
Probability of >= 5: 19.8%
Probability of >= 10: 9.9%
Probability of >= 20: 4.95%
Probability of >= 100: 0.99%
```

How can I reproduce this? If possible in C# but only a math equation would be enough.

Sorry for my english and sorry about the title which I didn't knew what to set to, feel free to edit my post if ever.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to make things a little easier, I'm going to assume that the figures you wrote might have a slight rounding error:

```
Probability of >= 1: 99%      change to 100%
Probability of >= 2: 49.5%              50%
Probability of >= 3: 33%                33.333%
Probability of >= 4: 24.75%             25%
Probability of >= 5: 19.8%              20%
Probability of >= 10: 9.9%              10%
Probability of >= 20: 4.95%             5%
Probability of >= 100: 0.99%            1%
```

The reason these are useful changes to make is that the random variable you're talking about (call it $X$) now has the property that $\mathbb P(X \geq k) = 1/k$. Maybe that's a bad change for me to make, and the real expression on the right side should be systematically less than $1/k$; if so, you can adjust it accordingly. Further, let's assume that $X$ is a continuous random variable, meaning that it can take on any value equal to $1$ or more.

This gives us something to work with. Continuous random variables are best described by either supplying a density function or a cumulative probability function (CDF). In this case, we essentially already have the CDF; since $\mathbb P (X \geq k) = 1/k$, it follows that $\mathbb P(X \leq k) = 1 - 1/k$. (Note that for any continuous random variable, $\mathbb P(X = k) = 0$, which is why we can be careless with the $=$ portion of the $\leq$ and $\geq$.)

Having the CDF gives us enough to generate the random variable. The idea is to start with $Y$, which will be a uniformly distributed number between $0$ and $1$, and set that equal to probability $\mathbb P(X \leq k)$; then, use that to unpack what $k$ would need to be. For example:

- If $Y$ is $0.2$, then set $\mathbb P(X \geq k) = 0.2$ and solve for $k$. Since we know that $0.2 = 1/k$, this tells us that $k = 1/0.2 = 5$.
- Similarly, if $Y$ is $0.5$, then we would have $0.5 = 1/k$, so $k = 1 / 0.5 = 2$.

And so forth. In terms of pseudocode, this is about one line:

```
1 / rand(0,1)
```

Executing this line of code should give outputs that behave similar to how the multipliers on that site behave.

As a last comment, let's talk about what happens if those probabilities you gave were exact and not approximations. You need to be able to model the function $\mathbb P(X \geq k)$ in some way; I approximated it as $1/k$, but maybe it should be something more like $1/(k + 0.001)$, or whatever. If you can find a better function that $1/k$ to model $\mathbb P(X \geq k)$, then it will just change the equation you solve at the end a bit. (Here, the equation I'm referring to is exemplified by the line $0.2 = 1/k$ above, which would become $0.2 = 1/ (k + 0.001)$ if you modified the function in that particular way.)

Note that any CDF you will write down necessarily must be invertible, because a CDF of a continuous function is always increasing (at least, on the values we're interested in here) and any strictly increasing function has an inverse. It may be challenging to find that inverse algebraically, though, depending on how complicated your function actually is.

---

**EDIT:** It turns out that my simplification *was* wrong! I poked around the site a bit and stumbled upon [this](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2807542.0), which shows how they're getting their numbers.

I suggested:

```
1 / rand(0,1)
```

but their procedure is actually equivalent to:

```
max( 0.99 / rand(0,1) , 1)
```

These processes will produce results that are close-ish to each other, but the bottom formulation consistently produce results a bit less than the procedure I originally guessed. This will push the overall probabilities back to something closer to what you gave to begin with.

Comment: You're amazing, thanks a lot for your time and clear explanations, I appreciate it so much. Have a wonderful day.

Comment: I've got a question tho, in your last pseudo-code, you use ``rand(0, 1)``, what do you mean by that? From 0.00 to 0.99, or from 0.00 to 1.00? Knowing that with most programming languages this will return a random floating-point that is greater than or equal to 0.0, and less to 1.0 (so from 0.00 to 0.99)

Comment: What I mean, conceptually, is a mathematical notion of a continuous random variable, uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. Such variables have probability 0 of being any particular number, so whether 0 and 1 are included doesn't matter. What that site uses, though, is an approximation of this (as it must be); it turns out to be equivalent to doing $k 2^{-52}$ where $k$ is an integer between $1$ and $2^{52}$ (inclusively).